# Confusion over Lagrangian function

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

When forming the Lagrangian of an optimization problem, why don't we include all constraints in the Lagrangian? For example, the optimization problem
$$
\begin{align}
 \max_{x}&\quad f(x)\\
 \nonumber \text{subject to } \quad & g_i(x) \le0,\,i=1,\ldots,m\\
\quad & h_j(x)=0,\,j=1,\ldots,l\\
\quad & x\in X
\end{align}
$$
has a Lagrangian of $
\mathcal{L}(x,\mu,\lambda) = f(x) + \sum_{i=1}^m\mu_ig_i(x) + \sum_{j=1}^l\lambda_jh_j(x)
$. Look at slide 17 of http://www.ise.ncsu.edu/fangroup/or706.dir/Lecture10.pdf.

Why didn't we dualize $x\in X$?

This raises the question of what sort of constraints are allowed to be lumped into $x\in X$? Does this depend on whether the constraint is *complicating* (that is, non-separable) or not?

I am especially confused since I've seen optimization problems that have constraints of the form $x\ge0$ and yet they are *dualized* into the Lagrangian. The constraint $x\ge0$ is not complicating (it is clearly separable), so why can't it be lumped into $x\in X$ and left out of the Lagrangian?

Comment: The Lagrangian (and the dual problem) depend on how the primal problem is written. If there are any constraints you don't want to dualize, you can include them in the $ x \in X $ constraint. One point of view is that you don't get a dual problem until you specify how to perturb the primal problem, and different ways of writing the primal problem give different ways to perturb it. Ekeland and Temam discusses the perturbation viewpoint, for example.

Comment: @littleO Thank you. So, if I understand correctly, this can lead to different Lagrangians for the same optimization problem, right? The reason I ask is that there is a result that states if the Lagrangian has a saddle point, then there is no duality gap (Thm.1 on slide 18 of the link in the question). Is it only required that I show that *any* of the Lagrangians that correspond to the given optimization problem have a saddle point in order to ensure there is no duality gap?

Comment: Once you write the primal problem in a certain way, both the Lagrangian and the dual problem are specified. If that Lagrangian has a saddle point, then the optimal value for that corresponding dual problem is equal to the primal optimal value. (It would be interesting to think about whether a stronger statement could be made, along the lines you suggested, but we don't need a stronger statement.)

Comment: @littleO Thanks so much, this is really clearing things up for me. Does the same hold true for KKT conditions? That is, once we write the primal in a certain way, there are a specific set of KKT conditions that may be different than if we write the same primal in a different way (by including different constraints in the $x\in X$ constraint)? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, that's correct.